# How to get current rendered value in renderer in grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I want my renderer to run only once for each row.

So obviously my renderer should look something like

```
renderer: function() {

    if (there_is_a_rendered_value_in_view) {
        return rendered_value_in_view;
    }

    return 'generate some return';
}
```

Is it possible to do?

So how to get `rendered_value_in_view`?

**UPD**:

seems like I'm not detailed enough.

Well, the generated value after that is changed outside the grid, so the question is: How to get **currently displayed** value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add boolean flag, and your `rendered_value_in_view` to the grid itself. And then in the renderer function check grid property and return it.

Update: from the Sencha docs here are list of parameters your renderer function will get:

```
value : Object
metaData : Object
record : Ext.data.Model
rowIndex : Number
colIndex : Number
store : Ext.data.Store
view : Ext.view.View
```

I think the last one will be your grid object.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer

Comment: "And then in the renderer function check grid property and return it." --- the question is **HOW** to do that

Comment: yes, it is view as a last parameter. And the question is still: how to get the value from it? ;-)

Comment: What value? I think I lost you there... Wanna go to the chat?

Comment: Well, initially my column hasn't been tied with any column in model. But probably it would be better to have the property that is `persist: false` instead. In that case it would be much easy to deal with. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It'd be fairly difficult to try and capture the rendered value. I think the better way would be to add another model to your field that contains this new value. You can use a convert method so that when the original value changes, the display value can also change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe -

```
...
there_is_a_rendered_value_in_view:false,
renderer:function() {

    if (!this.there_is_a_rendered_value_in_view) {
        this.there_is_a_rendered_value_in_view=true;
        return rendered_value_in_view;
    }

    return 'generate some return';
}
```

Comment: The question is how to get `rendered_value_in_view`. Sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: if you want to manipulate the data displayed, you want column renderer on appropriate columns. whatever you return from your column renderer will be displayed in the particular cell. there is no 'value' or 'data' at the row level to manipulate. If you want to manipulate the styling at row level, you override gridview.getRowClass (maybe I still dont understand your question)

Comment: uhm, I don't know how to rephrase it. I need to generate the value only once. After that every re-rendering should return the value that is currently displayed to user. It is modified from outside in runtime, so I cannot persist it somewhere in model.